# bodeplot phase in normal scale

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I've the following fuction:

```
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[{1/(((5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*
 (1.6672176431702952`*^-7)*(56000)*
 (56000 + 56000)*((56000*56000)/(56000 + 56000)))*(s)^3 + 
 ((5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(56000)*(56000 + 
  56000) + (5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(1.6672176431702952`*^-7)*(56000)*(56000 + 
  56000))*(s)^2 + ((5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(56000) + 
 (5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(56000 + 56000 + 56000))*(s) + 1)}, s], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

But I want the phase plot in a normal scale and not in a logarithmic scale. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BodePlot >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BodePlot.html):

[image]

So adding the option

```
ScalingFunctions -> {{"Linear", "dB"}, {"Linear", "Degree"}}
```

gives

[image]